# How to do bulk delete in JPA when using Element Collections?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa, jpa-2.0

I am having trouble working out how to do a bulk delete of a *Person* object using JPA, when the *Person* objects contain data stored using an *@ElementCollection*. Any ideas on how to do this would be much appreciated.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="at_person")
public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private long id = 0;

    @Column(name="name", nullable = true, length = 128)
    private String name = "";

    @ElementCollection
    @Column(name = "email")
    @CollectionTable(name = "person_email", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "person_id"))
    private Set<String> email = new HashSet<String>();
}
```

What I am doing at the moment is this, and it fails with a foreign key constraint error:

```
Query query=em.createQuery("DELETE FROM Person");
```

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: integrity constraint violation:
>   foreign key no action; FKCEC6E942485388AB table: PERSON_EMAIL

If it can be a pure JPA annotation rather than a Hibernate annotation that would be a bonus!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I'll let you interpret the part of the JPA 2.0 specification that mentions that a bulk delete operation is not cascaded:

> #### 4.10 Bulk Update and Delete Operations
>
> ...
>
> A delete operation only applies to
>   entities of the specified class and
>   its subclasses. **It does not cascade to
>   related entities**.

And the fact is that Hibernate won't cascade a delete to a collection table either. This has been reported in [HHH-5529](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5529) and the suggested approaches are:

> You could also (a) clean up the collection table yourself or (b) use cascading foreign keys in the schema.

In other words, (a) use native SQL or (b) use a cascade delete constraint at the database level - and you'll have to add it manually, I *don't think* you can use [`@OnDelete`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-collection) with the `@ElementCollection` annotation (same story as [HHH-4301](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4301) IMO).

Comment: Hmm, I am shocked that JPA would have such a glaring bug. This means if you are trying to use JPA to clear out data in a very large table you have to iterate over each object one by one, or hope manually turn on cascading delete! Maybe I should take another look back at JDO

Comment: @corydoras I mentioned the options. Your call.

Comment: Yes thanks for the info! Life is too short to spend time fiddling around with workarounds for something that should be simple (: For now we have code iterate over each object and manually delete them.

Comment: link seems broken for 5529... but should be available at https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5529

Comment: anyway, it might be part of the specs, but it looks like a huge limitation :(  if not going to be fixed in next specs of JPA, it would had been great if getting some non-standard non-JPA command in Hibernate... but that HHH-5529 seems opened since 2010... I guess also that a possible workaround would be to get completely rid off of ElementCollection, and wrap the base elements in their own Entity (although I guess it would not be particularly efficient...)

Comment: CriteriaDelete in Spec 2.1 does not mention cascade. Is cascade for bulk delete supported in JPA 2.1?